# .click not working for element located inside iframe on Safari browser

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, watir

I'm automating a web application on safari browser, and can't click on an element present inside an iframe. Same code is working on chrome and firefox.

I've tried different methods like `click`, `javascript` but nothing seems to work. Also, no error message is displayed for these methods. They get executed successfully and nothing happens on the screen. I've also tried clicking different elements in the hierarchy but no luck.

Below are the versions I'm using for this task:

ruby 2.6.0p0

selenium-webdriver: 3.142.3

Safari: 12.1.1

chromedriver: 74.0.3729.6

geckodriver: v0.24.0

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :safari
@browser.get 'https://www.splashmath.com/math-skills/first-grade/addition/add-using-pictures-within-10?from_page=Home'
@browser.find_element(xpath: "//a[@title='Practice Add using Pictures within 10 Worksheet']").click

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 20)

wait.until { @browser.find_element(id: 'sp-iframe') }
@browser.switch_to.frame('sp-iframe')
wait.until { @browser.find_element(xpath: "//div[@class='btn-choice pt-choice index-0']").displayed? }
sleep 5

# This is where nothing is happening:
@browser.find_element(xpath: "//div[@class='btn-choice pt-choice index-0']").click
```

I've also tried below code:

```rb
x = @browser.find_element(xpath: "//div[@class='btn-choice pt-choice index-0']")
@browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x) #=> Nothing happens
```

```
# This throws Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError

x = @browser.find_element(xpath: "//div[@class='btn-choice pt-choice index-0']") 
@browser.action.move_to(x).click.perform
```

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Can yo please share the html of the button and it's descendants.

Comment: @supputuri added in the description.

Comment: Did you switch to the iframe before clicking the element?

Comment: Yes, it's there in the snippet

Comment: Is this specific to safaridriver?  or also chromedriver and geckodriver also?

Comment: @orde specific to safari. Same code works fine on chrome and firefox (version mentioned in the description)